# Does mashiach know who he is?

Tags: messiah, messianic-redemption

Is there an opinion or two about whether mashiach (Either mashiach ben yosef or mashiach ben dovid) will know who he is or not? If so, what do they say? How will mashiach know it's mashiach?

Answer (score 0):

The Messiah will be a **male** king, who will reinstate the Kingdom of the house of David ([Rambam, Yad, Hilchos Melachim 11:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%90)). The Messiah can't be a woman, since women are disqualified from serving as a king ([Sifri, Shoftim 17:15](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%96#%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7)(%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7)); [Rambam, ibid. 1:5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90))

According to Jewish tradition, in every generation, there is a live human, who is fitting to assume the mantle of leadership of the Messiah. **However, that person himself is unaware this fact**.

When G-d decides that the time of redemption has come, He will then notify this person, instruct him regarding his mission, and empower him to fulfill it.

The precedent for this; is Moses, who was 80 years old, and until G-d appeared to him, and instructed him to redeem the Israelites, Moses had no clue that he was destined to be their redeemer.

**Source: Responsa Chasam Sofer (6:98).**

> והנה בהא דביאת בן דוד צריך אני להוציע הצעה אחת, והוא כמו שהיה משה
>   רבינו עליו השלום שהיה הגואל הראשון נזדקין שמונים שנה, **ולא ידע ולא
>   הרגיש בעצמו שהוא יהיה גואל ישראל**, ואפילו כשאמר לו הקב"ה (עי' שמות ג
>   י) "לך כי אשלחך אל פרעה", מכל מקום סירב ולא רצה לקבל על עצמו, כן יהיה
>   אי"ה הגואל האחרון
>
> ומיום שחרב בית המקדש, מיד נולד אחד הראוי בצדקתו להיות גואל, ולכשיגיע
>   הזמן יגלה אליו השי"ת וישלחו ואז יערה עליו רוחו של משיח הטמון וגנוז
>   למעלה עד בוא, וכאשר מצינו בשאול אחר שנמשח באה עליו רוח ממשלה ורוח
>   הקודש אשר מלפנים לא הרגיש בעצמו. כן היה בגואל הראשון וכן יהיה בגואל
>   האחרון, **והצדיק הזה בעצמו אינו יודע**
>
> ובעונותינו כי רבו, כבר כמה וכמה מתו ולא זכינו שיערה עליהם רוחו של
>   משיח, גם כי הם ראויים לכך, אבל הדור לא היה ראוי. אולם כשיגיע אי"ה,
>   יגלה אליו ה' כמו למשה בסנה וישלחהו או לישראל לבד או למלך אחד כמו לפרעה
>   לומר שלח עמי. עכ"ל

Comment: Does someone do something to be the mashiach? Or is that he's born "the mashiach" regardless of what he does?

Comment: The Chasam Sofer that I quoted, presumes that he will be a righteous person. See also Rambam (Yad, Hilchos Melachim 11:4) (linked above) that the Messiah will be a great Torah scholar, and a very religious person, like his forefather King David.