# Why is only Chabad very into Moshiach?

Tags: messiah, chabad, messianic-redemption, messianism

I'm only familiar with Judaism through chabad so I may not know how it is in other communities, but from what I've heard and seen, it seems that other sects and flavors of Judaism shun Chabad because of Chabad's zealousness with everything Moshiach.

But in the daily prayers, including in the amidah, we ask a few times for Moshiach; the Rambam says it is one of the 13 principals of faith, that we await his coming *every day*; and **we don't have the holy temple**, we are missing so many commandments that only can done there, and the holy presence of God which dwells there.

Shouldn't all Jews be begging God and making special programs and events (in MetLife stadium) for bringing Moshiach?

God told Moshe to make a Mishkan so his presence can be here among us on Earth, and then we had the Beis Hamikdash. So it's definitely something very critical for serving God.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106822/discussion-on-question-by-larry909-why-is-only-chabad-very-into-moshiach).

Answer (score 5):

The OP asks, “Why is only Chabad very into Moshiach?”
The answer is that the question is based on a false premise.
All those who follow true Judaism, are also “into Moshiach”, however they differ in approach.

Should all Jews be begging G-d to send the Messiah? Yes. Religious Jews pray for this thrice daily.

Should we put more feeling into these prayers? Yes. We should always make our prayers more sincere and heartfelt.

Should all Jews be making special programs and events (for example, like in MetLife Stadium) for bringing Moshiach? The answer is that if we knew that this is what’s holding up the coming of the Messiah, we would surely do so. However the notion that the making of Moshiach rallies will hasten his coming; is debatable.

The idea of hastening the Messiah’s revelation, is dealt with here
[Do we have to bring Mashiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40607/do-we-have-to-bring-mashiach/)

I note [there, that](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40607/do-we-have-to-bring-mashiach/112095#112095):

> We see that there has been a long standing debate regarding the
>   question of, is action required on our part to help bring the future
>   redemption. Those rabbis that believe that we need to take an active
>   role in creating the messianic era, are echoing Rav Kook’s position.
>
> It is interesting to note the “well known” (6th) Lubavitcher rebbe’s
>   position, as quoted by Rabbi Shulman, which advocated a more passive
>   approach. Contrast this with the current Lubavitcher approach, which
>   is to attempt to hasten the final redemption, and their mission is
>   centered on this goal.

When Rabbi M.M. Schneerson was alive, there was a strong movement in Lubavitch to recognize him as the Jewish Messiah. The debate whether or not Rabbi Schneerson himself hinted to his alleged status, or if it was merely his followers who proclaimed so, is moot. The point is, that the lives of Lubavitchers revolved around a Messianic culture, and they believed that the Rebbe’s “coming” was imminent, and all they needed to do was help hasten his revelation. Which is why at the time, Lubavitch was “very into Moshiach”, since they felt that the Rebbe was counting on them to make it happen.

After Rabbi M.M. Schneerson’s passing, most Torah Jews recognized that he isn’t the Jewish Messiah, since the potential Messiah is a [live human, living among us today](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/112093/does-mashiach-know-who-he-is/112094#112094).

Also, the Hebrew Bible makes NO mention about the Messiah failing to fulfill ALL the essential Messianic passages, and will have to return in the future to do so. If an individual fails to fulfill even one of these conditions, then he cannot have been the Messiah, which is why Torah Jews can never accept the Messiahship of any personality, however noble or well-intended, who died without ushering in the age of physical redemption.

Those who continue to insist that Rabbi M.M. Schneerson is the Messiah, are regarded as a breakaway Messianic sect, and are therefore shunned by mainstream Judaism.

Answer (score 1):

Because their Rebbe told them to focus on it.

However the Rambam discourages people from focusing on the details of what will happen and when.

see
Hilchos melachim 12:2
 the principle is simple "אֶלָּא יְחַכֶּה ויַאֲמִין בִּכְלַל הַדָּבָר".

there isnt much to talk about at an event without getting into details

Comment: The Rambam discourages focusing on the _details_ of what will or won't happen, not on Moshiach in general. In fact, in Hilchos Teshuvah and in Hilchos Melachim he says that all of the nevi'im and chachamim _desired_ (נתאוו) the coming of Moshiach.

Comment: @Meir i agree, but if the rebbe focused on specific programs or mitzvos that will bring moshiach then you are probably 'focusing on details'. the principle is simple אֶלָּא יְחַכֶּה וְיַאֲמִין בִּכְלַל הַדָּבָר. there isnt much to talk about at an event without getting into 'details'

Comment: How is what Chabad are doing (or what their Rebbe told them to do) considered "focusing on the details of _what will happen and when_" (emphasis mine), especially in the sense Rambam describes it in [Hikhot Melakhim 12:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.12.2?lang=bi&lang2=he) (i.e. busying themselves with the _Aggadot_ regarding what will take place in _Yemot ha-Mashi'ach_ and in what order, or dwelling on the _Midrashim_ regarding these matters, or making them dogma, or calculating when the _Mashi'ach_ will come)?